# Downloading a file in a new directory- Socket Programming

Tags: python, linux, sockets

I tried as hard is a could to create (or adapt) the following codes so that i can download a file (with any extension) from a server to the client in a new directory (to be more explicit, the client receives the file,downloads it in a new directory). I leave you the initial codes without my modifications,such in that way your changes won't be necessarly easier, but will help me where and why i'm wrong. Pay attention that codes are wrote in python and Linux OS(that's for directory paths). And do not forgot that i'm really new in Linux and Python. I tried many many variants but with many errors. Any help will be apreciated:).

```
**#CLIENT**

import socket                   # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()             # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname()     # Get local machine name
port = 60000                    # Reserve a port for your service.

s.connect((host, port))
s.send("Hello server!")

with open('received_file', 'wb') as f:
    print 'file opened'
    while True:
        print('receiving data...')
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print('data=%s', (data))
        if not data:
            break
        # write data to a file
        f.write(data)

f.close()
print('Successfully get the file')
s.close()
print('connection closed')
```

---

```
**#SERVER**

import socket                   # Import socket module

port = 60000                    # Reserve a port for your service.
s = socket.socket()             # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname()     # Get local machine name
s.bind((host, port))            # Bind to the port
s.listen(5)                     # Now wait for client connection.

print 'Server listening....'

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
    print 'Got connection from', addr
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print('Server received', repr(data))

    filename='mytext.txt'
    f = open(filename,'rb')
    l = f.read(1024)
    while (l):
       conn.send(l)
       print('Sent ',repr(l))
       l = f.read(1024)
    f.close()

    print('Done sending')
    conn.send('Thank you for connecting')
    conn.close()
```

Comment: You need to make sure you are calling the `socket()` function with the correct parameters. Also, I'd use some `try` constructs to zoom in on the point of failure and make the code more robust.

Comment: In my changes, i paid attention to the socket function and also tried the " try - except" method. The problem is that the new directory was created to the client using os.mkdir (tried also with os.path.join) but the file itself was not downloaded to the new directory (and i think not even to client directory).

Comment: This is Python 2 code (from the print statements...inconsisently used, and not using byte strings in the send function).  Make sure that's the version you are using if you want it to work.  The code basically works, except the final "Thank you for connecting" is added to the received file.  TCP is a streaming protocol, so you need a method to indicate how much data is part of the file.

Comment: Yes,i saw that is python 2 and the conversion to the python3 is in my list of changes. From those codes,i made 2 versions of communication(both of them work perfect). The problem is i want the client download the file from server in a new directory. That is my biggest dilemma. I used 'os' library with 'mkdir' and 'chdir' and the code only creates the new directory,but do not download the file in that directory.